# "pip install Django" gives exception

Tags: python, django

I am trying to install django on Windows 10 using "pip install django" in command prompt and it is giving me this exception. What am I doing wrong here?

```
C:\Users\Amit>pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-1.9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: django
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 731, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 841, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1040, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 343, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 314, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 82, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python35-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\django'
```

Comment: open your cmd in admin mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an administrator command prompt to install Python packages. Here's how to [Start a Command Prompt as an Administrator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813(v=ws.10).aspx).